# Function to exchange value between variables

Tags: python, function, scope, transactions, global

I am trying to write a function that makes "transactions" between "adresses" (variables) by exchanging values between them. I want to make it so that I can just write the reciever address, sender address and transaction value inside the arguments and get permanent changes in the addresses values/balances.

```
addr_1 = 1000       #Variable value = Balance
global addr_1
addr_2 = 200
global addr_2
addr_3 = 0
global addr_3

def tx(from_addr, to_addr, tx_input):
    if from_addr < tx_input:
        print("TRANSACTION ERROR: Balance too low")
    else:
        from_addr -= tx_input
        to_addr += tx_input
        "Transaction Output:"
    return "From Address:", from_addr, "To Address:", to_addr
```

I already figured out that I have to make the variables global and that the problem are the local variables in the function. I cannot figure out a way to calculate with and change the "addresses" that are supposed to be put into the arguments

Comment: Marking variables as `global` only affects the current scope. Meaning you "should" mark them inside the `tx` definition. **BUT**, globals in general aren't a good thing to use, especially in a case like that. Make some kind of container (e.g. list, dictionary) for the addresses and pass it to `tx` explicitly, together with what some kind of id of specific `to` and `from` addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you 2 technique. The first one is quite simple, to update the value in the main scope you can just return the value modified in the function and unpack them to your original variable:

```
addr_1 = 1000       #Variable value = Balance
addr_2 = 200
addr_3 = 0


def tx(from_addr, to_addr, tx_input):
    if from_addr < tx_input:
        print("TRANSACTION ERROR: Balance too low")
    else:
        from_addr -= tx_input
        to_addr += tx_input
        "Transaction Output:"
    return from_addr, to_addr

addr_1, addr_2 = tx(addr_1, addr_2, 200)
print(f"addr_1 = {addr_1}") # Output: 800
print(f"addr_2 = {addr_2}") # Output: 400
print(f"addr_3 = {addr_3}") # Output: 0
```

The second option will be more like you wanted and will used python Immutability with class object. So you will need to create a class and instead of having just a variable you will have a class with a property called Balance. When you will pass this object to the function, it will also change it outside the scope of the function. Like this:

```
class Adresse():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.Balance = val
    
    def update(self, value):
        self.Balance += value
        
        

addr_1_class = Adresse(1000)
addr_2_class = Adresse(200)
addr_3_class = Adresse(0)


def tx_with_class(from_addr_class, to_addr_class, tx_input):
    if from_addr_class.Balance < tx_input:
        print("TRANSACTION ERROR: Balance too low")
    else:
        from_addr_class.update(-tx_input)
        to_addr_class.update(tx_input)
        "Transaction Output:"
    return from_addr_class, to_addr_class

tx_with_class(addr_1_class, addr_2_class, 200)
print(f"addr_1 = {addr_1_class.Balance}") # Output: 800
print(f"addr_2 = {addr_2_class.Balance}") # Output: 400
print(f"addr_3 = {addr_3_class.Balance}") # Output: 0
```

The output will be the same in the to exemple! It's just a matter of preference!